# How to control fluid flow speed / velocity

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to Blender, and I'm having trouble regulating the water's speed from the sphere while using water simulation.

I want the water to start flowing at 35 litres per minute and stop after 25 minutes. I'm using Blender 4.0, and while changing the inflow object's object size and resolution seems to help. Is there any method I can do this?

Comment: If your question is how to stop the water at frame X you can simply keyframe the Use Flow option of the Inflow object but it has nothing to do with speed, maybe reformulate?

Comment: I really just want to know how to adjust the water flow

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to scale down the *Inflow* object:

[image]

Comment: appreciate it brother! thanks